# Modified Euler's method overestimator

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Does the Modified Euler Method always overestimate the true solution values?

Here is the modified Euler Method:

$w_0=\alpha$

$w_{i+1}=w_{i}+\frac{h}{2}[f(t_i,w_i)+f(t_{i+1},w_i+hf(t_i,w_i))], i=0,1,\ldots,N-1$

Because based on my calculations and data for a problem that I'm working on, I'm getting that it consistently overestimates the true solution...

Is it supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not always overestimate the solution for all $f$, though it might do so for a particular one. Set $f(t,y) = \sqrt{t}$ and $w_0=t_0=0$. We find that 
$$ w_1 = 0+ \frac{h}{2} (0+\sqrt{h}) = \frac{h^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2}.$$

On the other hand we can compute the real solution explicitly and find that the true value in 
$t=h$ is $\frac{2}{3} h^{\frac{3}{2}}$.